# Matrix Position

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I need to figure out how to return the matrix position of the largest value in a given matrix. For example:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

A simple method of finding the maximum of the matrix would be:

```
maximum = max(max(matrix))
return maximum
```

For this matrix, the maximum is the int value: 9.

However, I am slightly lost when it comes to finding the value's exact matrix position. I know that in matrices the upper-left corner is considered (0,0) and the values (i,j) (given that i,j ε int) are incremented by one each position further from (0,0)-- i increases horizontally and j increases vertically.

The correct output for this matrix should be (2,2).

Any pointers?

Comment: The more straightforward solution would be to use two `for` loops (one for each dimension), iterate the whole matrix, and check eacg spot manually. This is far too broad currently though. Get a start, and post back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
mat = np.arange(1,9).reshape(3,3)         # Creates your example matrix
maxVal = np.amax(mat)                     # Returns 9 for your example
locMax = [np.where(mat == maxVal)[0][0],np.where(mat == maxVal)[1][0]]   # Returns (2,2) as list
```